# Haskell Generating Incorrect QR Code

Tags: haskell, qr-code

I'm using [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/qrcode) library to generate a QR code for Google Authenticator.

Unfortunately when I then scan the QR code, it's incorrect. Uploading the QR code to [this](https://webqr.com/) website provides the following:

`OTPAUTH%3A%2F%2FTOTP :0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Something seems to go wrong after `totp` but the next part of the input is `%2F` which has already appeared twice and been handled correctly.

When I put the input string into [this](https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/) online generator, the QR code is correctly generated.

Here is my code:

```
testQR :: IO ()
testQR = do
    let path = "hello.pgm"
    arrayToFile path
        . toArray
        . fromJust
        . encode (fromJust $ version 1) M Alphanumeric
        $ "otpauth%3A%2F%2Ftotp%2FLabel%3AJames%3Fsecret%3DGEZDGNBVGY3TQOJQGEZDGNBVGY3TQOJQ%26issuer%3DMyCompany"
```

I have considered using `haskell-qrencode` instead but then I get an error saying  `Missing C library: qrencode` even after installing `qrencode`. Feel free to suggest a fix for this instead of the issue above.

Comment: I wouldn't assume version 0.1.2 of anything to be working correctly, but AFAICT, version 1 of QR does not support strings of that length. See e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/kizzx2/haskell-qrcode/issues/1) with that library.

Comment: @molbdnilo, version number magnitudes are famously meaningless in general, and that's certainly true of Haskell package versions. That said, it does sound as though version 0.1.2 of *this* library is immature.

Comment: @molbdnilo I've tried changing the version and that hasn't helped the QR code is now just unreadable. Even though that issue report said it was fixed in a new commit (I ensured Stack pulled that commit rather than whatever is on Hackage). Do you have any idea how to fix the issue with `qrencode` so I can try and use that instead?

Comment: Most distributions distinguish between libraries and the "development" versions of libraries (which include extra stuff for when you want to build a new application that uses that library, as opposed to just running an already-built application). On Debian derivatives, these usually have the same package name with `-dev` attached; on Fedora derivatives they attach `-devel`. Do you have the development package for `qrencode` installed, too?

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried installing `qrencode-dev` on Ubuntu before making this post but it doesn't exist. After total guess work I found that while the regular library is `qrencode` the dev version is `libqrencode-dev`.

Comment: FYI, it doesn't remove the guess work entirely but apt search now exists (where the old `apt-get` was lacking) so you can do things like `apt search qrencode | grep dev`)

Comment: Similarly to `apt search` you can use `apt-file` to find packages that contain the file you need. In this case it is apparent you're missing either the header `qrencode.h` (i.e. `grep 'include' * -R` in the package if it isn't immediately obvious).  We can find this with `apt-file search 'qrencode.h'`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Ah that should make things a lot easier, thanks!

Comment: It's better to add the package name “qrcode” to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not a direct solution to my question, the following is what I've ended up with.

I'm using `haskell-qrencode` to generate the QR code followed by `JuicyPixels` to create a PNG image.

My function is now as follows:

```
genQR :: String -> Base.String -> IO ()
genQR user s = do
    let secret = mkSecretString s
        url = mkURL user secret
        path = "hello.png"
    qr <- encodeString url Nothing QR_ECLEVEL_M QR_MODE_EIGHT True
    let pixels = map (map (\case
                                0 -> 255 :: Pixel8
                                1 -> 0)) $ toMatrix qr
        height = length pixels
        width = length $ head pixels
        pxGen = \x y -> pixels !! y !! x
        image = generateImage pxGen width height
    writePng path image
```

Answer (score 0):

I had good success with [diagrams-qrcode](https://github.com/prowdsponsor/diagrams-qrcode).

Comment: I've been looking at that but, according to its documentation, it requires you to use `haskell-qrencode` or `qrcode` to generate the code itself, see the issues in my post. After getting `haskell-qrencode` to install I tried `diagrams-qrcode` but unfortunately it plunges me into dependency hell so I don't think I can use it.